# ImageMagick messing up + enlarging GIFs

Tags: node.js, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using node's `gm` module with imagemagick and it seems to be really messing up some GIFs that I need to resize.  Is there a good configuration that works well for GIFs?  For example, I tried resizing this GIF:

https://postimg.org/image/4ngzc5igh/

And it ended up looking like this:

https://postimg.org/image/xolblk2wh/

Code:

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
gm(file.path).gravity('Center')
  .modulate(config.brightness)
  .noProfile()
  .resize(config.width, config.height, config.geometry)
  .crop(config.width, config.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't speak `node`, but can hopefully help you. You are dealing with an animated GIF, and they are highly optimised between frames to only overpaint the changed parts of the image so as to reduce size.

Normally, you need to use `-coalesce` to split the image into its individual frames, and recreate each frame **including** all the optimised away parts. You then do your resize of all the frames and put them back together and reoptimize the layers.

The command looks something like this:

```
convert animated.gif -coalesce -resize 200x100 -modulate A,B,C -layers optimize result.gif
```

If you examine the frames of your bear, you can see there are 37 and they are all different sizes and at different positions so as to overpaint specific parts of each frame:

```
identify bear.gif
```

**Output**

```
bear.gif[0] GIF 500x500 500x500+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[1] GIF 262x449 500x500+121+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[2] GIF 262x449 500x500+121+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[3] GIF 262x449 500x500+121+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[4] GIF 262x449 500x500+121+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[5] GIF 246x449 500x500+137+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[6] GIF 266x449 500x500+137+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[7] GIF 256x449 500x500+171+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[8] GIF 263x453 500x500+171+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[9] GIF 239x453 500x500+195+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[10] GIF 260x453 500x500+195+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[11] GIF 265x453 500x500+190+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[12] GIF 244x453 500x500+190+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[13] GIF 257x453 500x500+177+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[14] GIF 249x445 500x500+177+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[15] GIF 270x444 500x500+156+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[16] GIF 247x449 500x500+156+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[17] GIF 269x449 500x500+121+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[18] GIF 247x443 500x500+121+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[19] GIF 258x457 500x500+110+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[20] GIF 243x457 500x500+110+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[21] GIF 272x457 500x500+81+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[22] GIF 240x457 500x500+81+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[23] GIF 261x444 500x500+60+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[24] GIF 250x446 500x500+60+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[25] GIF 270x446 500x500+40+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[26] GIF 245x443 500x500+40+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[27] GIF 249x443 500x500+36+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[28] GIF 261x445 500x500+36+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[29] GIF 254x445 500x500+43+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[30] GIF 277x444 500x500+43+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[31] GIF 251x444 500x500+69+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[32] GIF 270x444 500x500+69+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[33] GIF 258x457 500x500+83+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[34] GIF 285x457 500x500+83+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[35] GIF 248x443 500x500+120+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
bear.gif[36] GIF 266x443 500x500+120+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 1.802MB 0.000u 0:00.009
```

You can see the individual coalesced frames using this command:

```
convert bear.gif -coalesce miff:- | montage -tile 8x -geometry +5+5 - frames.gif
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like it could be the issue, I'll check it out and then mark your answer-- Just a question, would hte -coalesce flag cause any issues with converting jpegs or other flat images (ie: can I just leave it in the command for large directory of mixed image types)?